# Trying to Compute Difference Between Two fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, mongodb-compass

Good evening. I have a project in MongoDB and i keep getting an error while trying to run my last querie. The dataset i have is about wines. What i want to do is to print the wines that match the Red wine category and that are at least 20 years old (i have a start date-the date that they were put in their barrels- and an end date, which is the date they were bottled). Note:i want all these fields to be printed at the end and be printed according to their rating.

let me give an example of the data:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("638f389d8830abb3f19aaf51"),
tconst: 'tt0040030',
wineType: 'Red',
Brand: '#brand',
startYear: 1990,
endYear: 2002
rating:6.6}
```

When i am using the $match function for my three criteria all is working just fine but i haven't figured out how to subtract the two date fields so i can find the wines that are at least 20 years old and print the results properly.

Answer (score 1):

Query

- you need to refer to a field to compute the difference so you need `$expr` and aggregate operators
- the bellow keeps `red` wines, with `years difference>=20`, and then sorts by `rating`.

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=63948885424f6130d7f1217a)

```
aggregate(
[{"$match": 
   {"$expr": 
     {"$and": 
       [{"$eq": ["$wineType", "Red"]},
         {"$gte": [{"$subtract": ["$endYear", "$startYear"]}, 20]}]}}},
 {"$sort": {"rating": -1}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB, the `$where` query operator is used for comparing the fields or documents that satisfy the JavaScript expression. We can also pass a `string`.